# srcds not found?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

I'm setting up CSGO dedicated server on a Windows 7 system.

I have followed the complete steps mentioned [Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers)

But I'm stuck at the section "Starting the server". The error I get is:

```
command>> srcds not found.
```

I have updated the complete `steamcmd` with no errors. Why am I not able to start the server?

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of your error, it seems like you're still in SteamCMD.  Did you quit SteamCMD and return to the/open a command prompt before running srcds?  srcds is a separate program, not a command within SteamCMD.

You'll need to open a standard Windows command prompt (not a SteamCMD prompt), change to the directory where srcds is, and enter the srcds command.  (You could also use a .bat file to launch it, but that's another layer you may not want to introduce at this point...)